# Correct settings for PHPMailer via a gmail account

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I am trying to set up a simple email function on my site with PHPMailer. I am testing out using my own gmail account and simply sending a test email to myself. I am running MAMP PRO on a Mac.  I have seen loads of questions on this and spent an afternoon researching it but everything I have seen comes down to conflicting advice on the correct settings,  use port 487 versus 465 etc etc. I have tried multiple combinations of the various settings below ($mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls' with port 587, but 'ssl' for port 465 for example. I keep getting this connection error.  If anyone has some thoughts on whats wrong with this I would be very grateful.  I have remmebered to include the relevant files in my code.

```
 mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();  
 $mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
 $mail->From     = "me@gmail.com";
 $mail->AddAddress("me@gmail.com");
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->username = "me@gmail.com";
 $mail->password = "mypassword";
 $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
 $mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
 $mail->WordWrap = 50;

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else 
   echo 'Message has been sent.';
 }
```

The error message is - "Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good - I'd definitely go with TLS on 587. This error is usually down to the environment you're running in - check these things:

- That your DNS is working (try substituting an IP for smtp.gmail.com)
- That `stream_socket_client` or `fsockopen` (or fopen wrappers in general) is not blocked or disabled in php.ini
- Check that your firewall isn't blocking you
- [Read the troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)