# PHPMailer won't send my emails there are also no errors

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've been using the default mail function of PHP before but decided to use another service for emailing features. I used PHPMailer but it is not working.

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "xxx";

$mail->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com', 'Name');

$mail->addReplyTo('xxx@gmail.com', 'no-reply');

$mail->addAddress('xxx@gmail.com', 'Name');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

The code also doesn't echo any errors.

Comment: [Use the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/), base your code on [the gmail example provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki). Also, search before posting - this question has been answered hundreds of times before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct settings for PHPMailer via a gmail account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310003/correct-settings-for-phpmailer-via-a-gmail-account)

Answer (score -1):

It does not echo any errors, but I think it also doesn't echo 'Message sent!'

Try the following

Append the brackets

```
$mail =  new PHPMailer();
```

Set debug to messages AND ERRORS for testing purpose

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

To send HTML Body, either after setting  `$mail->Body` call

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Or use the Method to set HTML body which will combine both of them:

```
$mail->MsgHTML('This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>');
```

Try this and see if it works

EDIT:
Also look that the casing is as suggested (I am not sure if this may give errors, but just to be sure)

```
$mail->SetFrom
$mail->AddReplyTo
$mail->AddAddress
```

Comment: Official sample for GMAIL found here: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail

Comment: Please don't suggest obsolete changes, and don't link to obsolete docs.

Comment: Also brackets are not needed with `new`, function names are not case sensitive in PHP, changing `SMTPDebug` from 2 to 1 will mean that you won't see the vital error messages from google. Bad idea!